# Where to place an XSD 1.1 assert?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation, xml-validation, xsd-1.1

I'm trying unsuccessfully to use an `xs:assert` to validate based on the values of two attributes.  I keep getting

> `s4s-elt-must-match.1`: The content of `data` must match `(annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*))`. A problem was found starting at: `assert`.

I've looked thru a bunch of questions.  I even copied one of the answers given, but even it gives the same error.  It's telling me the format of the test is invalid, but I can't find any example that does it differently.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

TIA

Here's the answer I copied, with the error inline as a comment:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">

  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="min" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:assert test="@min le @max"/>
    <!--s4s-elt-must-match.1: The content of 'data' must match (annotation?, (simpleType | complexType)?, (unique | key | keyref)*)). A problem was found starting at: assert.-->
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Edit:
Here it is with the assert inside the complexType, showing a different error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning"
  vc:minVersion="1.1">

    <xs:element name="data">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:attribute name="min" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:int"/>
            <xs:assert test="@min le @max"/>    
<!-- s4s-elt-invalid-content.1: The content of '#AnonType_data' is invalid.  Element 'assert' is invalid, misplaced, or 
 occurs too often. -->                      
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible issues:

1. Make sure your XSD processor supports XSD 1.1.
2. Move the `xs:assert` element to within `xs:complex`:

Change from

```
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="min" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:assert test="@min le @max"/>
  </xs:element>
```

to

```
  <xs:element name="data">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:attribute name="min" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:attribute name="max" type="xs:int"/>
      <xs:assert test="@min le @max"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that moving it inside complexType simply resulted in a different error.  I've added that to my question.  Thanks

Comment: Whoops, I overlooked that.  That me check if Eclipse/Java support XSD 1.1.